# how to store .cbproj files in GIT to prevent merge problems

Tags: git, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

We are using Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.4 with C++, and all of our code base is in GIT.

Some files cause us problems when saved in GIT, and these are the `.CBPROJ` files.

They are XML files read by the IDE to know about the projects.
When 2 developers work on the same project, there is often conflicts when merging a PR.

Also, even if a developer has only modified some `.CPP` files, the `.CBPROJ` get changed, too. Just reshuffling of the files, but it is very annoying and causes a lot of noise when reviewing a PR. As a matter of fact, people just skip reviewing the PR and wait for the build to know if something is wrong or not.

How could we make it so that we have fewer problems with `.CBPROJ` files in GIT?

We discovered lately that some parts of `.CBPROJ` act like binary: some CDATA section, so we cannot indicate to GIT that `.CBPROJ` are text files.

Comment: You *can* (and perhaps should) mark these as binary files, to prevent Git from mis-merging them. That won't help with merging them, but will at least stop the *mis*-merges that you may get otherwise. [Remy Lebeau's suggestion of normalizing the files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74542766/1256452) will likely help a lot since that will prevent irrelevant non-changes (structural but non-semantic changes) from being seen *as* changes.

Comment: AFAICR, `.cbproj` are environment-specific file, with zero-added value to project and maybe the easiest way to solve problem of merging is unversion and gitignore it

Comment: @LazyBadger what do you mean: nvironment-specific file, with zero-added value to project ? 
they seem to store information for building the project, quite important to save in source control. No ?

Comment: I didn't suggest removing this file, only *not version it*, if 1) it changed constantly 2) these changes are relevant only to single local workspace (both conditions are ANDed). If, otherwise, these **changes are important, relevant and MUST be shared** (I don't use Builder a lot longer than decade, thus - *can't know it*), you can follow already noted ideas and, f.e., use DprojNormalizer in smudge|clean filter for simplicity and some type of automation

Comment: If your developer has not changed the project file intentionally, for example by adding a new file to the project, they should not commit the changes. This policy can be extended to all changes: If the developer commits something by accident, the pull request should be rejected and corrected.

Comment: @VLL, the problem is you do not know always if you changed it or not. projects are constantly evolving: we have one big groupproj with more than 100 cbproj. So sometime we add or remove files from the cbproj, or change options. 
at the end, we have like 20 cbproj changed, but maybe only one or two significantly.
it a pain to check in the PR. I'll try to Remy Lebeau suggestion, but it seems disruptive to the workflow, no way to automate it

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize the contents of the CBPROJ file before checking it in to any version control system. There is a 3rd party tool for Delphi projects named DprojNormalizer, it may work for C++Builder projects too, since they have a similar project structure.

https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/

https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/24/dprojnormalizer-for-xe7-and-xe8/